# Crontab not triggering execution when installed during AWS CentsOS EC2 bootstrap

Tags: linux, unix, cron, centos7

I am deploying a cron file `abcd.cron` in `/etc/cron.d/` location during EC2 bootstrap time using Cloudformation user-data(Uses clod-init). This is not triggering the execution(Checked `/var/log/cron` log file) unless I modify the cron file `/etc/cron.d/abcd.cron` (updating time). I tried to restart `crond` service in the cloud-init section after cron file copy, but that didn't help.

Is there a way to fix this issue during bootstrap time without manual modification ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your CloudFormation:

```
crontab -l > /tmp/mycrontab
echo '0 * * * * ls -la' >> /tmp/mycrontab
crontab /tmp/mycrontab
```